# Referring leaflet popup for bring to front or back

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I am building application shows data on a leaflet map as popups using vue.js. I want to use "bringToFront" function that is part of leaflet object, on leaflet popup. How can I call the function - whether as L object, or l-popup component?

Vue-leaf-let library enables rendering leaflet elements as components like "l-marker" or "l-popup". functions like "l-add" for markers, for example, are used by adding "@" symbols (as vue component).

Unfortunately I haven't found any way of conditionally use bringToFront() or bringToBack functions for popup layers.

I have tried passing @bring-to-front="condition" into the component like doing so with @add of marker;

Using ":ref" on popup bring the "vue" component without leaflet methods.

````
Component:
``` <l-layer-group ref="layerGroup">
            <l-marker v-for="items"
                      :ref="`someRef`"
                      :lat-lng="item"
                   //succeed:
                      @add="($event)=>open($event, item)">
                <l-popup :lat-lng="item"
                         //not succeed`enter code here`
                          @bring-to-front => someFunc()
                         :ref="`popup${someDiffId}`">
                    <popup-content :key=item.key" :item="item"/>
                </l-popup>
            </l-marker>
        </l-layer-group>```

from @open I use:
```            open(event, item) {
                const marker = event.target;
                this.$nextTick(() => {
                    marker.openPopup()
                    condition? marker._popup.bringToFront():marker._popup.bringToBack()
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        marker.remove()
                    }, 30000)
                })
            }
```
````

By using "@add" on marker by referring "marker._popup" I succeed, but not from $this.refs and not from watchers.

Referring the object from ":ref" is referring to a vue component without @bringToFront method, so I am using reference from marker.

Answer (score 2):

Well, When using all components inherits "layer" of leaflet - using "@add" inside make the reference of rendering to map/marker/layer as "leaflet object",
That's mean just add "@add":

```
<l-popup  @add="($event)=>func($event, leafletItem)">
```

and inside func:

```
  methods: {
         func(event, leafletItem){
          const popup = event.target;
          condition ? popup.bringToFront() : popup.bringToBack()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@bring-to-front is not event of adding to map leaflet object, while @add - is the event, so @add($event) will have reference to leaflet object.
Bevause of that you just use "@add" for popup component.